# MATLAB: IF function based on a String's name

Tags: string, matlab, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have 60 different strings (Book01, Book02, ..., Book60).
I want to do a certain procedure only for Book045 until Book58.

How do I write an if statement, so that the procedure is only performed for any String Book045 until Book58? For example:

```
Book48
    If (name of string = Book045 to Book58)
      My Procedure
    else
      Nothing
    end
```

Thanks.

Comment: If all names are of the type 'Book###', you could get the index of the book simply with `str2double()`, and then just test that the index is in your range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the names in a cell array

```
books = {'Book01', 'Book02', ..., 'Book59', 'Book60'};
```

Then you can extract the value in each name and check on that in your loop

```
for ii = 1:numel(books)
    val = erase( books{ii}, 'Book' ); % Remove the 'Book' prefix
    val = str2double( val );          % Convert to number
    if val >= 45 && val <= 58
        % do something in this range
    end 
end
```

Comment: Wolfie, you were right. I got confused about his dataset, I thought that it contains characters instead of a string.  Upvoted yours. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @Wolfie. Brilliant! This is perfectly right for what I asked, but please excuse me for not having been to clear or inaccurate, but what if all the books are character arrays. (For example Book01 is a 1x202040 char.) I understand that I should change the code like so: `books = {Book01, Book02, ..., Book59, Book60};`, but how to adapt the rest of your solution to fit this? Thanks again.

Comment: You could do `books = strsplit(books, 'Book')` to create the cell array first, then you wouldn't even need the `erase`.

Comment: @Wolfie. Thanks for helping me, but I think the answer might be simpler? What if the answer could be as simple as something like this: `if Book == Book45|Book46|Book47|Book48|Book49|Book50|Book51|Book52|Book53|Book54|Book54|Book56|Book57|Book58     My Procedure      end`? I just need this if function to work? What am I dong wrong in this? Thanks for the trouble.

Comment: You've not made it clear in your question what your data types are or how you're looping over them. Without that info, my suggestion is the most robust thing I can suggest. The option you've put in the comment won't work because it's unclear what `Book` and `BookXX` are? They aren't in quotes like strings or chars, `==` won't work with chars, etc. Please edit your question or ask a new (and improved) one including a [mcve]

Comment: @Wolfie. Thanks. I did so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639018/matlab-perform-for-loop-or-if-statement-only-for-specific-character-arrays