# MATLAB: Perform "For-loop or IF-statement" only for specific character arrays

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, char

I have 60 different character arrays (Book01, Book02, ..., Book60). (For example Book01 is a 1x202040 char.). I want to do a certain procedure only on Book45 until Book58.

How do I write an IF-statement or FOR-loop, so that the procedure is only performed for character arrays Book45 until Book58? For example:

```
Book05  % Inserted Array for test

if Book45|Book46|Book47|Book48|Book49|Book50|Book51|Book52|Book53|Book54|Book54|Book56|Book57|Book58 % If inserted array is Book45-58     
   % Procedure to be performed on "Inserted Array", only if Book45-58    
else
   % No Procedure on Book01-44 or Book59-60
end
```

Thanks

Comment: put all those arrays in a single datastructure, like a struct or a cell array. Then iterating becomes trivial.

Comment: is it Book045  or Book45 ?

Comment: @dpdp. Sharp eye. It should be Book45. I have corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in the comment, better to put all arrays into one big array. If you insist on calling a particular array you can write:

```
 for ii=45:58
     a=eval(['Book' num2str(ii)]); % 
     % Procedure to be performed on a
 end
```

but everywhere I see to try and avoid `eval`...

Comment: Thanks this works. But I think we might need a IF-Statement, or even this solution coupled with an IF-statement. The reason is, that I need to specify something clearly with an `else`. If not, even choosing `Book05`, my procedure is carried out even though it should only be carrying out on Book45-58. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @div that shouldn't be a problem this way. Just iterate over the whole range and use an if- statement based on the index.

Comment: @JHBonarius. Thanks but this is exactly what my question is about in the first place, but how to actually do it?

Comment: @Div I wrote an answer, but I don't understand "even choosing Book05, my procedure is carried out even though it should only be carrying out on Book45-58" <-- that is a false statement. With the shown code, the procedure should not be called for `Book05`. If it does, you did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just putting the comment in an answer, so I can write some code. I actually lost my matlab license yesterday, so cannot test it.

```matlab
for i = 1:[largest book number]
    book = eval(['Book' num2str(i)]);
    if i >= 45 && i <= 58
        % procedure for book45 until and including book58
    else
        % procedure for other books
    end
end
```

IMHO the only reason not to use `eval` is because it is slow (and possibly error prone), but in this case it's not an issue.
But instead of having all these separate arrays, you could put all books in a cell array and drop the `eval`.

edit: but now I read that you have "No Procedure on Book01-44 or Book59-60". If the `else` statement is empty, then the answer by dpdp is fully sufficient.

Comment: If I have a snag somewhere on my side I apologize. Thanks for the help! I still do not know what I am doing wrong? I have made a new question to hopefully be more informative of where my snag might be. Please be so kind to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643656/matlab-perform-a-procedure-only-for-specific-character-arrays

Comment: @Div sorry, I literally lost my license yesterday, so cant test any code. (Switching to python...)