# Matlab: Perform a procedure only for specific character arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement

I have 60 different character arrays loaded in my workspace (Book01, Book02, ..., Book60). For example, Book01 is a 1x202040 char.

I'm working in a script file, and trying to separate the last sentence("RandomInfoAtEnd") of Book45 until Book58:

```
WholeBook = Book50; % Call Array for test

for i = 1:60
    book = eval(['Book' num2str(i)]);
    if i >= 45 && i <= 58
        % Procedure to separate last sentence.
        Chr = convertStringsToChars(WholeBook);
        SearchedUnit = '.!?' ;    % Sentence end punctuation
        idx = ismember (Chr, SearchedUnit); 
        Loc = find (idx, 2, 'last'); % Find second last sentence-ending-punctuation
            if numel (Loc) < 2
                error ('the requested character cannot be found')
            end
        SecondLastLocation = Loc (1);
        AllLocations = find (idx);
        RandomInfoAtEnd = extractAfter(WholeBook,SecondLastLocation);
    else
        RandomInfoAtEnd = ''; % No sentence separated
    end
end
```

Right now I have a problem only with the IF-statement or FOR-loop logic, in such a way that `RandomInfoAtEnd = ''` for any array that is called.
My procedure is working fine, as it separated the last sentence perfectly from any array, but what am I doing wrong with the `FOR-loop/IF-statement`?
Thanks.

Comment: First things first. Get rid of 60 dynamic variables. Use a cell-array or a struct instead. Also please create a [mre]

Comment: Next, use the debugger to step through your code as MATLAB evaluates it, and see what it is actually doing. You should find the issue much quicker that way than asking strangers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the problem is just with the use of the IF-statement or FOR-loop.

Comment: The for loop and if statement are fine. What are you trying to accomplish? `RandomInfoAtEnd` is overwritten every loop iteration, so only the last loop iteration (`i=60`) is meaningful. This is something you can discover by using the debugger, as I suggested. Knowing how to use the debugger is a core competence for a programmer. Start here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that if I inserted `Book50` as array, `i` should match the array number. I have manually changed `i`, and will further seek a more automatic way.